How i can dispose a widget in pyqt6?
Im trying to dispose a widget of mine its inside another class as a different component ,i want to dispose it in order to re-render the state of some of my buttons.
Here is the class i want to re-render :
class PlotScreen(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.paused = False # My button State


And here i call my main class where it have a header with a button for navigation , i want when i navigate back to my home page to trigger an event or a dispose method to re-render the entire widget PlotScreen from the start (sweep_button_screen renders the PlotScreen).
class MenuApp(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        def create_screens(self):
        dashboard_screen = QWidget()
        dashboard_layout = QVBoxLayout(dashboard_screen)

        sweep_button = QPushButton("Sweep")
        sweep_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.navigate_to_screen(1))

        dashboard_layout.addStretch(1)
        dashboard_layout.addWidget(
            sweep_button, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter
        )

        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(dashboard_screen)  # Index 0 (Home Page)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(sweep_button_screen)  # Index 1

    def navigate_to_screen(self, index):
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(index)

    def navigate_to_home(self):
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)


Sorry but it's not really clear what you're asking, and the word "dispose" can have two very different meanings in English: "get rid" or "arrange". Please try to make yourself more clear, and provide a proper [mre], because that "PlotScreen" is just an empty widget, it's not actually used in "MenuApp", and self.stacked_widget is never created. Also check the syntax in the post preview before submitting the updates, as right now that code will throw a syntax error due to wrong indentation.
